# Bootstrap Collapse force expand all

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bunch of different sections that have their own collapse elements.  I have already implemented the jquery to expand and collapse them.

jQuery:

```
$('.collapse').each(function (index) {
    $(this).collapse("toggle");
});
```

HTML Snippet:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active" id="General"><a href="#">General</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active">                                                                                                                                                                             
        <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">                                                
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#generalQuestions" href="#collapseFour">Q. Can I choose my own Username and Password?</a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseFour" class="accordion-body collapse">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">A. Yes, you can choose your own Username and Password.  We suggest using your email address for your Username, but any username that is between 8 and 20 characters long could be used.  A secure Password should be 8 to 20 characters long, with no spaces, and contains at least one special character.  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#generalQuestions" href="#collapseFive">Q. Can I update by email address online?</a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseFive" class="accordion-body collapse">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">A. Yes, but I have no idea how right now.  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <a href="#top" class="btn btn-mini top"><i class="icon-arrow-up"></i> Back To Top</a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RmK2h/

There are a couple different problems I'm having:

1. In Internet Explorer the functionality only works on the second click and is very jumpy. With it working on the second click the button text is incorrect.
2. If I open one of the elements and then click the expand button all elements expand except the one that was originally opened, it collapses.  Essentially the `.collapse("toggle")` functionality simply changes the mode to either open or closed it isn't concerned with the state it's already in.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the IE problem is an issue with Bootstrap. From Googling a bit, it looks like the `collapse` functionality breaks in every other release in some form or another. So, unless you go with something other than the `collapse` function I'm not sure you're going to be able to fix that. I sort of fixed it in IE (the expand/collapse buttons don't get out of sync anymore) and fixed your second problem with this code:

```
$('.expandcollapse').click(function () {
    if ($(this).html() == "<i class=\"icon-white icon-plus-sign\"></i> Expand All") {
        $('.collapse:not(.in)').each(function (index) {
            $(this).collapse("toggle");
        });
        $(this).html("<i class=\"icon-white icon-minus-sign\"></i> Collapse All");
    }
    else {
        $('.collapse.in').each(function (index) {
            $(this).collapse("toggle");
        });
        $(this).html("<i class=\"icon-white icon-plus-sign\"></i> Expand All");
    };
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cC3ys/)

Answer (score 1):

[Samsquanch's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027535/bootstrap-collapse-force-expand-all/15028834#15028834) works correctly, but in my case I was still able to get `collapse` out of sync once in a while.

The reason was that the data attribute `data-parent="#selector"` is in conflict with the wanted `"expand all"` behavior. The Bootstrap documentation points out:

> To add accordion-like group management to a collapsible control, add
>   the data attribute `data-parent="#selector"`.

So when `"expand all"` functionality is needed, it's better to leave that data attribute out or remove it before expanding.