# show all bootstrap accordion

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to program a link for bootstraps accordion that will show all the accordion panels when clicked and then when clicked again all the panels hide.

I have it about 90% working, except the top panel is acting weird. When I click on the show all the very first time it will hide and the other menu's open up. When toggled back and forth though it starts to work as it should.

My jQuery looks like this

```
$('#accShow').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).text() == 'View All') {
        $(this).text('Hide All');
        $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
    } else {
        $(this).text('View All');
        $('.collapse').collapse('show');
    }
    return false;
});
```

and I have tried adding this, but it had no effect:

```
$('#collapseOne').collapse("show");
```

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027535/bootstrap-collapse-force-expand-all

Comment: Can you provide it on JSFiddle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Took and modified [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027535/bootstrap-collapse-force-expand-all/15028834#15028834) :

```
$('#accShow').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).text() == 'View All') {
        $('.collapse:not(.in)').each(function (index) {
            $(this).collapse("toggle");
        });
        $(this).text('Hide All');
    } else {
        $(this).text('View All');
        $('.collapse.in').each(function (index) {
            $(this).collapse("toggle");
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add id to your button View all and 
add script :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#idButtonViewAll').on('click', function(e){
         jQuery('.accordion-body').each(function(){
               jquery(this).addClass("in");
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: I already have an id on my viewAll button...and how would adding the class in help? I'm looking to open all the separate panels not add a class..

Comment: To get your panels open at loading, they need the class 'in' !

Comment: I'm not looking to get all my panels at loading, I am trying to get everything to show when you click a button. I already have this happening using jQuery, except the first panel closes instead of opens like the rest of the panels. I have done copious amounts of research and almost every article says that the method I posted above is preferred over the in class.