# Buttons to open ALL and close ALL of Twitter Bootstrap drop down menu's onClick

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Thanks for talking the time  for looking into my issue.

To clarify further, I have provided some example code below. If you click on a 'publication' menu item first and then the close all button, it doesn't close all and i want it to...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head    content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap dropdown</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
    body {
            background: #222222;
        }
        .nav-tabs {
            border-bottom: none;
            margin-left: 0;
        }
        ul.nav .dropdown.open {
            background: #323433;
        }
        ul.nav .dropdown.open button span.caret {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
            transform: rotate(90deg);
        }
        ul.nav .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus, ul.nav .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
            color: #262626;
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: #000000;
        }
        ul.nav .dropdown-menu li.active {
            background: #008265;
        }
        ul.nav .dropdown {
            border-bottom: solid 1px #3f3f3f;
            position: initial !important;
            clear: both;
        }
        ul.nav .dropdown .btn-default {
            background-color: transparent;
            border: none;
            display: block;
            padding: 12px 30px 12px 20px;
            color: white;
            margin-left: 0;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: left;
        }

        ul.nav .dropdown .btn-default .caret {
            position: absolute;
            right: 15px;
            top: 22px;
            border-top: 4px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
            border-left: 4px solid white;
            border-right: none;
            -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
            transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
        }

        ul.nav .dropdown ul.dropdown-menu {
            position: initial;
            width: 100%;
            background: #323433;
            padding-top: 0px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            border-top: none;
            border-right: none;
            border-radius: 0;
        }

        ul.nav .dropdown ul.dropdown-menu li a {
            padding: 5px 5px 5px 30px;
            color: white;
        }

        ul.nav .dropdown ul.dropdown-menu > .active > a {
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: transparent;
            outline: 0;
        }
        ul.nav .dropdown.open ul.dropdown-menu {
            display: block !important;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
                <ul id="accordion" class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                                aria-expanded="false">
                            Library
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Carriers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Threats</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Mitigations</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of menu-->
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            Publication
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Library Threat Changes</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Library
                                Mitigation Changes</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Published Data</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of menu-->
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            Publication
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Library Threat Changes</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Library
                                Mitigation Changes</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Published Data</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of menu-->
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            Publication
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Library Threat Changes</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Library
                                Mitigation Changes</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Published Data</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of menu--></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <button class="openall" style="display:inline-block;">Expand</button>
      <button class="closeall" style="display:inline-block;">Collapse</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>

 $('.openall').click(function(e){
        $('#accordion').removeClass('collapseMenu')
        $('.dropdown').removeClass('open')
        $('.dropdown').addClass('open');
        $('.dropdown button').attr('aria-expanded','true');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

 $('.closeall').click(function(e){
        $('.dropdown').removeClass('open')
        $('.dropdown button').attr('aria-expanded','false');
        $('#accordion').removeClass('collapseMenu')
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    // ADD SLIDEDOWN ANIMATION TO DROPDOWN //
    $('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e){
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown();
    });

    // ADD SLIDEUP ANIMATION TO DROPDOWN //
    $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e){
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp();
    });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Collapse - Expand All](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057505/bootstrap-collapse-expand-all)

Comment: @Jim Dropdowns are different than accordions

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin

https://github.com/CWSpear/bootstrap-hover-dropdown

and `addClass('open')` to expand all the dropdown item.

`removeClass('open')` to collapse them.